# Docker run, after docker-compose build could not translate host name “db” to address: Name or service not known

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have currently a system built with docker-compose, it creates a Django application.
I've use a database inside a container (postgresql) in my testing build.
I want upload my docker image to docker-hub.

When i run

```
$ sudo docker-compose up
```

Server goes up sucecesfully

```
Recreating rest_api_db_1 ... done
Recreating rest_api_web_1 ... done
Attaching to rest_api_db_1, rest_api_web_1
db_1   | 
db_1   | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db_1   | 
db_1   | 2021-06-08 07:22:10.698 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1   | 2021-06-08 07:22:10.699 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1   | 2021-06-08 07:22:10.699 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1   | 2021-06-08 07:22:10.708 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2021-06-08 07:22:10.719 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-06-08 07:15:22 UTC
db_1   | 2021-06-08 07:22:10.726 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web_1  | Operations to perform:
web_1  |   Apply all migrations: admin, api_bus_routes, auth, contenttypes, sessions
web_1  | Running migrations:
web_1  |   No migrations to apply.
web_1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
web_1  | Performing system checks...
web_1  | 
web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1  | June 08, 2021 - 07:22:12
web_1  | Django version 3.2.4, using settings 'rest_api.settings'
web_1  | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
web_1  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

But when i tried to build and run

```
$ sudo docker-compose build
$ sudo docker run rest_api_web
```

I get an error

psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

My Docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate &&
                      python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

My Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

My settings.py

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB', default='postgres'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER', default='postgres'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD', default='postgres'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_HOST', default='db'),
        'PORT': "5432"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Docker-compose can only run with all services and creates its own network on with `db` exists. But if you run a single container, the network doesn't exist and db-container can not be found. Either run the docker-compose, or in your settings.py define where the db is with a valid host.